# workflow 2010 will show a Date equal to 01/01/0001 inside the email, if the Date is empty

Tags: 2013, workflow, development, designer-workflow, date-time

I am working on SharePoint server 2013, and i create a new Workflow 2010 inside Sharepoint designer 2013. now inside the Workflow i set an email which contain the following value:-

```
[%Current Item:Contract Review Date%]
```

now if the "Contract Review Date" value is empty , the email will contain the following value `01/01/0001`instead of showing empty string. So can anyone advice how to fix this problem.

I mean how to allow if the contract review date is empty then to show empty string inside the email, instead of `01/01/0001`?

Comment: The `Contract Review Date` column is of type Date/Time. Does the column have a default value?

Comment: @Submits Contract review date is of type Date ,, and it does not have a default value. also when i view/edit a list item the value will be empty.. but not sure why inside the workflow it will show 01/01/001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable, ReviewDateForEmail of type string.

Run a check,

```
If [%Current Item:Contract Review Date%] is not equal to 01/01/0001
Set ReviewDateForEmail to [%Current Item:Contract Review Date%]
(if desired)
Else Set ReviewDateForEmail to There is no set review date for this item.
```

In your email, use the ReviewDateForEmail. This will result in either the contract review date, or an empty string, or a fixed string if desired..

Comment: but is there a way to set the ReviewDateForEmail to be empty string inside of "There is no set review date for this item" ??

Comment: @Erix now i can not define this inside the workflow designer 01/01/0001 !!! did you try it your self ? also the real value will be 01/01/0001 00:00:00 even if the field of type Date only

Answer (score 4):

Date fields are never truly empty, so the option doesn't exist. An "empty" date field is actually set to `1/1/0001`.

So for your specific project, forget the whole "storing the string values of the dates" thing, that won't work. Instead, set up the workflow to perform the action if Date field is greater than `1/1/0001`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but in my case i still want to send the email even if the contract review date is empty.. but i want its value to be empty inside the email..

Comment: Yes you can as you need to change the condition that if it is not greater than 1/1/0001 than you can pass empty string.

Comment: i am unable to check if the contract review date is greater than 1/1/0001 .. as on the date value selector the minimum value will be 1601 ... not sure how simple thing can go crazy inside sharepoint ... can you advice ?

Comment: There is a small workaround given here....https://howardmcd.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/how-to-check-if-a-date-field-is-blank-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: so all these workarounds just to show the date field correctly inside the email.. you know i will remove this field from the email...

Comment: I am just providing you the options. so you can reach out to your problem & solve it.. Just helping you .... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40604/discussion-between-hardik-and-john-g).

Comment: yes i know and thanks for your useful replies.. but what annoyed me is that simple things can go crazy ... how come the review date will show as empty string inside the create/edit/view forms when the value is empty.. but if i want to use it inside a workflow it will be shown as 01/01/0001 00:00:00  if the value is empty .. and i have a Date field not a DateTime field so why its value will show the time 00:00:00 !!!if i implement the workaround i will complicate the workflow just to get a date field on my email...

Answer (score 1):

Create an initiation variable of type string and don't set a default value. Before you write Contract Review Date to your email, use an if statement to check if the date is greater than 1/1/1900. If it is, use the date... if not, use the null variable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local variable of type date/time. Do not assign any value.

```
if condition : If [Contract review Date] is equal to [Local Variable].
```

This should work for your condition to be working.

Comment: Monica - that doesn't work for me. When I set up a local date/time variable, don't initialize it, in an e-mail it displays 12/31/1899 4:00:00 PM. If a Current Item date that has been left blank, in an e-mail it displays 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM. All we are looking for is a way in an e-mail to have a local variable that either displays the current item date if not blank, or nothing if left blank. No one seems to know how to do this simple task in all the forum articles I've read, nothing suggested ever works. Why is this so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column (lets say 'IsBlank_CRD') in the list with formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Contract Review Date]),"Y","N")
```

Now in workflow check if 'IsBlank_CRD' is 'Y' or 'N' , to do the further processing in email.