# SharePoint 2013 workflow bug with pulling date/time field into workflow variable?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-designer-workflow

The company I work for has an employee termination list and a workflow for processing these terminations.
The workflow essentially has two phases: an initial batch of emails sent as the first phase upon submitting the term and a second phase for the second batch of emails.
The workflow is supposed to loop/pause until the LDE (Last Date of Employment) is met and compared with today's date/time, where it will then fire off the second batch of emails.
While the workflow loops, it is supposed to change arbitrary column every minute.  The reason for this is two fold:
1.) I'm using a CurrentDateTime variable which checks the "Modified" date column and uses it for the value of CurrentDateTime.
2.) The loop should check for any changes made to the LDE var, if any changes are detected, it should then update LDE's value.

I've upgraded the original workflow from a 2010 SP Workflow to a 2013 SP workflow because I noticed there was a new loop feature in the SP2013 engine where I could hopefully accomplish this objective.

I'm using a LDE (Last Date of Employment) variable to capture the date provided by a user in the SP form.
As you can see in the workflow history, it pulls the date/time correctly the very first time.  However, every other time thereafter it pulls a value of 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z (Monday, January 1, 0001).  The column it's pulling from is not empty, it is a required field which always requires a date.

I'm confused at to why this date is pulled correctly the first time, but never again.  I've tried encapsulating the later steps in different app steps, steps, and stages but I am unable to pull the value more than once.

I would be incredibly grateful if anyone could share some information or perspective regarding this.

Thanks

[image: Workflow History]

[image: Workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013]

Comment: [Date Time column in SharePoint in not an empty field, check Hardik answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181551/workflow-2010-will-show-a-date-equal-to-01-01-0001-inside-the-email-if-the-date)

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my initial post, this field is NOT empty, and actually pulls the correct value only once at the very beginning of the workflow.